# Configuring additional two monitors to an Ubuntu12.04 installed system

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors

Can anyone please guide me how to configure additional monitors to my Ubuntu12.04 installed system? What kind of information should I need before installing anything, like drivers or something?
I am quite new to linux and have no good idea. Please let me know if my question is incomplete or you may need additional information.

Cheers!
Zia

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use 3 monitors total?  Will you be using one GPU?  What kind of GPU will you be using?

It should be as simple as plugging them in and going to 'System Settings -> Displays' to configure them the way you'd like.

You can move them around, set resolution, etc.

Comment: Actually initially I was using NVIDIA graphics driver to connect my laptop with additional two hp monitors. My laptop had windows 7.
But now I have installed Ubuntu12.04, clearing Windows 7. And now I don't know how to configure those additional monitors with my laptop. 
I installed some NVIDIA softwares from Ubuntu Software Center but don't know what to do next. 
I am sorry but I am dumb in Linux but I really wanna learn.

Comment: Are you using an HP dock to connect your laptop with the monitors?
Go to System Settings -> Additional Drivers which should display all the available video drivers you can download/install.

Comment: I am using Dell dock since my laptop is Dell. But those two monitors are HP.

Comment: I am using Dell dock since my laptop is Dell plus 2 HP monitors.
From Additional Drivers option I found the following options:
1. NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 331)[Recommended]
2. NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates)(version 331-updates)

I installed the first option but after rebooting my screen went blank. From recovery mode I again switched to the previous screen resolution since it was adjusted to the lowest possible resolution after NVIDIA installation.

Now Additional Drivers showing "This driver is activated and currently in use" for the first option

Comment: Have you plugged in your monitors and what is their status?

Comment: Yaa, they are plugged-in.

Comment: Monitor Status:
DVI:No Signal
HDMI:No Signal
VGA:No Signal
Auto-switch soruce:On
Default source: DVI
Recommended Settings: 1920X1080-60Hz

And after that the monitor is going to sleep

Comment: If you go to System Settings -> Displays, can you see your two extra HP monitors listed there?  If so, when you click on them, is the on/off button turned to on?

Comment: I cannot see my HP monitors in the Display option. This is the main problem. I was good so far but still cannot have a clue about those monitors. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Dell laptop with a DisplayPort MST hub, you'll need newer drivers in order to use it. You may find these posts useful:

- [Displayport 1.2 MST/daisy chain - Dual Monitor setup - Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369946/displayport-1-2-mst-daisy-chain-dual-monitor-setup-intel-graphics/552094)
- [Ubuntu 14.04 Dell E7240 - Docked - doesn't recognize second monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465507/ubuntu-14-04-dell-e7240-docked-doesnt-recognize-second-monitor)