# What are some large, office printers that work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing

I work for a company that let me convert an entire office to ubuntu as a test-site for the feasibility of converting over to ubuntu on all or most of our machines. We have a Canon iR3880i and have had difficulty finding proper drivers.

As such, we're in the market for a new printer for the entire office and I was hoping to get some feedback about which large-scale printers have good drivers that are compatible with Ubuntu.

We're running 14.04 LTS on custom built machines. This will be a network printer that scans, emails, has 4 drawers, a bypass stack, and a stapling finisher (at least).

Any suggestions would be helpful.

T

Comment: we do not typically make hardware reccommendations here. CHeck hardware comatibility lists.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I apologize. I just wanted to make a post for anyone who had searched here looking to get a large office printer working on their system (I appended a response). I actually already found one and wanted to let everyone know. **Truly**, my motive is to build my experience for a [ticket](http://askubuntu.com/questions/591731/dell-xps-13-2015-ubuntu-compatibility-displayport-mst) I can actually contribute to, but lack the experience points to comment. :(

Comment: Nice idea, I suggest you contribute to one of the many hardware contability lists

Comment: http://www.fsf.org/resources/hw

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendations are off topic.

Comment: In general HP printers have excellent Linux support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post this for future reference for anyone in my shoes:

I found that Konica/Minolta C-454e. The drivers on the site were perfect for our office and we haven't had any issues since installation (02-01-2015).

I found my [drivers](http://onyxweb.mykonicaminolta.com/OneStopProductSupport/SearchResults?products=1621) on the [Konica Minolta Site](http://kmbs.konicaminolta.us/wps/portal/web/home/products/office-systems/color-mfps/bizhub-c454e) which were last updated in 2013 by the manufacturer.

I am very pleased with the performance.