# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes upon re-activating after lock screen

Tags: 14.04, xorg, intel-graphics, freeze, lock-screen

Since today my systems seems to freeze whenever I lock it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and then try to unlock it. I am using a dual monitor setup I have read [AskUbuntu Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369946/displayport-1-2-mst-daisy-chain-dual-monitor-setup-intel-graphics/552094#552094) to get it working, and upon trying to unlock my system one display is re-activated and one stays black. I can move the mouse pointer but cannot click or type anything and I can't unlock the system by blindly typing my password.

What can I check to resolve this problem? Could this be prompted by the "fix" I used to get the multi display setup working with my hardware?

Laptop is a DELL Latitude E5540 with an Intel HD Graphics 4400 and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 720M. I am using the Intel and everything worked fine up until today. Also I am using Gnome 3 instead of Unity, but it happens with both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)