# How long after release will the last LTS get a HWE kernel?

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

The Vivid release is just around the corner so as a 14.04 user I'm curious to know when there'll be a supported kernel upgrade available. I have several machines running on Utopic's kernel and I'll have to upgrade within 3 months. I'd like to get testing started sooner rather than later.

I've been trying to find out when (and I'll include as far as I've got as an answer) but if anybody knows of a plan, I'd be very interested to know.

Comment: I'm guessing it depends on the demands of proper LTS testing, how stable the kernel seems based on field experience with the release, and whether any packages might need to be backported for the new kernel (as sometimes happens with xorg updates that also come with HWE, but I guess that is rare for kernels).  But thanks for the data!!

Answer (score 5):

We have seen a few HWE stacks now so can can look at the repo-creation dates for a bit of historical background:

- `trusty-updates/linux-meta-lts-utopic` 2014-11-24, 32 days after Utopic
- `precise-updates/linux-meta-lts-trusty` 2014-04-25, 8 days after Trusty
- `precise-updates/linux-meta-lts-saucy` 2013-11-08, 22 days after Saucy
- `precise-updates/linux-meta-lts-raring`  2013-05-05, 14 days after Raring
- `precise-updates/linux-meta-lts-quantal` 2012-11-14, 27 days after Quantal

An average would suggest something like 1-2 weeks for a `-proposed` update and 3-4 weeks for an `-updates` update after the release date.

Comment: But that's in `-proposed`. I think it took about 2-3 months after the Utopic release to see the Utopic HWE kernel in Trusty main archive. I don't want to enable `-proposed` for the system globally, because well, unsupported buggy updates potentially.

Comment: @gertvdijk Fair point. I have updated the answer to use `-updates` versions.

Comment: Thanks. Also, another note -- the kernel might have been available 32 days after the release, but the matching Xorg packages weren't. That took another while still before I could run it stable on my workstation. A long time actually, until February 9: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/trusty-changes/2015-February/017940.html