# USB3 Docking Station for Dell XPS 15

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, xps, docking

So I've recently started using Ubuntu and I mist say its the first time I've used an open source / Linux destro ever and so far I'm happy and impressed with its offerings.

Now recently I've been looking to treat myself a little and purchase a new workbook. 
I've decided on the Dell XPS 15: http://www.dell.com/uk/p/xps-15-9530/pd?oc=cnx9525 however I also want to be able to hook the laptop up to a docking station. One situated in my house and one in my office, with which I will use to connect a few monitors to via the docking station.

The docking station that I have been looking at is the Dell USB 3.0 Ultra HD Triple Video Docking Station D3100: http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=bsd&cs=ukbsdt1&sku=452-bboo

Now after having used ubuntu 15.04 for the past few weeks as my daily driver OS I want to know if..

a) The docking station will work with Ubuntu as I can see it requires drivers to be installed and after having a small look online, I cannot really find a definitive answer.

b) Has any one successfully run a similar set-up with the same / very similar products?

If anyone has any knowledge on the matter it would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Adam

Answer (score 11):

There is now a [displaylink driver for Ubuntu](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu). Installing this in Ubuntu 15.10 fixed all problems with multiple displays on the Dell D3100.

Comment: if you use Intel GPU than workaround is needed. See http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a **XPS 13" (2015)** and the same docking station as you linked to.
I was mainly interested in a dual monitor solution with the added benefit of more USB ports. What you've probably read on this forum and other places is that USB 3.0 support on Linux is not optimal. I've tested the dock on Ubuntu **14.04** and **14.10**, *not* **15.04**

To sum my situation up:

The following **does** work with the docking station:

1. Ethernet
2. USB hub

The following **does not** work

1. Power (The laptop does not charge via the USB 3.0 port)
2. Display port (The screens are not extended. I have not tested the HDMI ports)

**Regarding multiple display:** [daisy chaining with Display Port (MST) is supposed to work with Ubuntu 14.10/15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369946/displayport-1-2-mst-daisy-chain-dual-monitor-setup-intel-graphics/552094#552094). I upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 and still only got mirrored screens. I'm trying to update the Kernel to 3.17 as we speak. I'll let you know if I succeed.

As you are on 15.04 I'm not sure how much of this applies to your pc.

Hope it helps.

---

**Update**
The combination of Ubuntu 14.10 and kernel 3.17 made Display port MST work on my machine. Not via the Dock, but directly from the mini display port on the machine. I never succedded in installing the driver mentioned on [cweiske's blog](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/thinkpad-ultradock-screens.htm) but as far as I could make out the needed drivers should be included on 14.10.

I'm going to leave my set up as it is for now. I've got two external monitors (connected via the laptop's mini DP), USB hub and ethernet via the dock, and have to connect a power supply directly to the laptop.

---

## solution

After updating the kernel to v. 3.17 I lost WIFI. The final solution to this was [updating to 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632108/wifi-not-worrking-after-kernel-update)

So on 15.04 I'm using Display ports MST to use dual monitors, a separate power supply directly connected to the laptop and the docking station connected via usb 3.0 as usb hub and ethernet.

Answer (score 2):

The D3100 is not designed to charge your laptop as far as I am aware.  I believe only the USB-C/Thunderbolt dock does that.

I do have 2 external displays working via the d3100 on ubuntu 14.04; 1 is 1200p and the other is 1440p running simultaneously with the 4K touch screen.

Basically, you need to install the displaylink package (http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) and be using lightdm/unity (I had no success with GDM/Gnome).  Then, you can see the monitors connected to the dock via the Display settings in ubuntu.  In brief, the displaylink package provides the evdi kernel module alongside a dlm service that monitors the dock for newly connected monitors and transfers the content of the display via the displaylink software layer.  Unfortunately, this ties up 30% of 1 core at all times.