# Wifi not worrking after kernel update

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom

I updated Ubuntu from version 14.04 to 14.10 and [installed kernel v. 3.17](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/thinkpad-ultradock-screens.htm) ,as described on this blog, to gain Display port MST support. This gave me MST support but WIFI does not not after the kernel update.

```
sudo lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280
```

returns

```
02:00.0 Networkcontroller [0280]: 
Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter 
[14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
```

w1 is not found by modprobe

```
sudo modprobe w1
modprobe: FATAL: Module w1 not found
```

Using a WIFI dongle ( <del>wifi works with that</del> ) I've tried to do

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

The headers are installed as expected but the bcmwl kernel source does not support my kernel version

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-3.17.1-dp-mst is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module  build on kernel: 3.17.1-dp-mst (x86_64)
```

The make.log from the attempted bcmwl install says that `alloc_netdev` only was given 3 arguments but requires 4, and also that it's undeclared.
I'm not able to upload the make.log at the moment...

Does anybody have suggestions on how I get my WIFI back?

---

It turns out that I didn't have internet access with the wifi dongle after all. I'll try to reinstall the bcmwl kernel again when I have an ethernet connection.

Comment: What is the result of `dpkg -l | grep bcmwl`

Comment: Where did you get that kernel image from?

Comment: And it is not `w1` it is `wl`

Comment: @Pilot6 I got the kernel from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.17.1.tar.xz
And thanks for spotting the `w1` / `wl` mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed an unsupported kernel. The driver does not build. What is the point of installing it? you could install kernel 3.19 to 14.04, or upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04.

You built mainline kernel form source. It was not a best idea for Ubuntu.
Anyway you do not have to build kernels yourself. All mainline kernels are available at [Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

The solution is to boot with the previous kernel using grub menu.

Then Upgrade your system to Ubuntu 15.04. You will get  3.19 kernel.

Comment: Thanks, I booted the old kernel version and updated to 15.04 with `sudo do-release-upgrade`. Got MST and WIFI now.

Comment: @Pilot6 I am experiencing a similar problem, although booting with the previous kernel didn't solve my issue. I request you to take a look please - https://askubuntu.com/q/995494/672640.